# PHP Dropdown Validation

Tags: php, html

This is the part of an edit page in PHP
Here I am displaying the country which is already selected by the user and this code works fine.
And in this case there are3 countries only. 
If I have a lot of countries, then I have to validate with each country and the no: of lines of code will increase.
Is there any other option to acheive this?

```
Select Country: 
<select name="country">
<?php if($country == "india") { ?>
    <option value="">-Select Country-</option>
    <option value="india" selected>india</option>
    <option value="us">us</option>
    <option value="uk">uk</option>
<?php } else if($country == "us"){ ?>
    <option value="">-Select Country-</option>
    <option value="india">india</option>
    <option value="us" selected>us</option>
    <option value="uk">uk</option>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <option value="">-Select Country-</option>
    <option value="india">india</option>
    <option value="us">us</option>
    <option value="uk" selected>uk</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The code you posted could be from `The Daily WTF` ;)

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460243/using-php-to-populate-a-select-select/2460555

Answer (score 2):

load the countries into array

```
$countries = array("india", "us", "uk");
```

then,

```
<select name="country">
<?php
  foreach($countries as $c)
  {
     echo "<option ";
     if ($c == $country) echo "selected";
     echo ">$c</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this your update county page then do below

first get the selected country from database  let

```
$row['country']='india';
```

and your country Array is

```
$countryArray = array ('india','us','uk');
```

then do below

```
<select name="country">
<option value="">-Select Country-</option>
<?php foreach( $countryArray as $country) { ?>
<option value="india" <?php if($row['country']===$country ) { ?> selected ="selected" <? } ?><?php echo $country?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Woah, a two seconds difference.

Comment: did you mean $country instead of $row['country'] in the first bit of code?

Comment: @Ben i write `$row['country']` bcoz usually we fetch data from database in `$row=mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: Doesn't make sense in your context

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I believe you would be looking for something like this:

```
<?php

$selected = "india";

$countries = Array(
    ["india"] => "India",
    ["us"] => "United States",
    ["uk"] => "United Kindom",
);

foreach( $countries as $id => $country ){
    echo '<option value="'.$id.'"', $selected == $id ? ' selected' : '' ,'>' . $country . '</option>';
}

?>
```

Excuse me, I have not coded in PHP in a while, but I believe this is correct.

Comment: interesting mix of , and . :)